# Calculate time difference and accept negative time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form for which I enter my work hours. I also enter how long my breaks are, then I click on a button and want to transfer this to another sheet. However, in my VBA script for the button I want to take the `breaks - TimeValue("00:30:00")`. So that if I have taken a break that is `00:40:00` long I would get a `00:10:00` entry in the result sheet. So far so good. The issue is then I take a break that is shorter than 30min, lets say `00:20:00` min. Then I would want a `-00:10:00` in my result sheet, but instead my script breaks and returns a run-time error.

code:

```
Dim breaks As Range, breaksAsDate As Date
Set breaks = inputSheet.Range("G2")
breaksAsDate = breaks.Value

breaksAsDate = breaksAsDate - TimeValue("00:30:00")
destCell.Offset(0,6).Value = breaksAsDate
```

Comment: Have you looked into `DateDiff` yet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function - and if you are going to store the results in a database (instead of each date value to use in the calculation) then you will need to save something like negative minutes instead of a datetime value (date values cannot be negative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that Excel (and VBA) don't allow negative values for dates and times. You can calculate with something like `- TimeValue("00:30:00")` but if the result is negative, you will get a runtime error in VBA. In Excel, a negative date/time is displayed as `#########`.

You will have to solve 2 issues: First is how to *calculate* the negative time and the second is to *display* it in Excel.

*Calculation* is easy, but you need to understand that dates and times are stored internally as `Double`. The Integer part of the number gives the number of days passed since the 31.Dec.1899. The remainder stores the time part as a fractal of the day: 1:00am = 0.042 (=1/24); 6am = 0.25
This internal representation makes it easy to calculate with dates, you can simply add or subtract date values. And the data type Double can easily handle negative values. You can change your code to

```
Dim breaks As Range, breaksAsDate As Double
Set breaks = inputSheet.Range("G2")
breaksAsDate = breaks.Value
destCell.Offset(0,6).Value = breaksAsDate - TimeValue("00:30:00")
```

Now you have to solve the second problem: How to *display* this negative value in Excel. If you format the cell to display a time value, you will see the infamous '######' for negative values.

I can see 4 + 1 ways to deal with that, but I admit none is ideal.

- Display the time as decimal
- Display the time and live with the '######'
- Display the time as fraction of a day with 1440 (=number of minutes/day) as denominator
- Display the time and use a decimal format for negative numbers.

The last uses a formula to display the time, eg

```
=IF($B3<$A3,"-"&TEXT($A3-$B3,"HH:MM"),TEXT($B3-$A3,"HH:MM")).
```

Now the time is displayed "correctly" for negative times, but content is no longer numeric and you can't calculate with it. Usual workaround is to have two columns, one with the numeric amount (you could hide that column) and one with the formula.

[image]

---

There is also another workaround in Excel, but I would not recommend it: Change the date format to "Use 1904 date system". File->Options->Advanced (you have to srcoll down to find the settings)

[image]

Excel will be able to show negative dates/times with that setting, but be aware that when you switch that setting and you have already data in that sheet, all existing dates will be off (by 4 years). This setting will be valid for the whole workbook.